# Replacing Italic with markdown formatting or em tags

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, html, text-editors

I have content in google docs that is being converted to HTML. The main trick is that there are a number of italic sections which I would like to add `<em>` tags or *markdown asterisks*.

I tried pasting it into Word and using find and replace with wildcards, with formatting set to italic, but it finds each character separately rather than the italic section as a whole.

If I save it out as html from word of course the formatting is utterly ridiculous (I need clean html, not a font-tag riddled mess)

Answer (score 2):

Don’t search for a wildcard; just search for a blank search (“Find what”) string, with italics specified.

[image]

`^&` is the “Find What Text”; i.e., what was found, like `&` in *nix’s `ed`, `sed`, `vi`, `vim`, `csh`, `bash`, etc… programs.  (And of course you could use asterisks or underscores just as well as `<em>` and `</em>`.)